# Is a basis of $V$ a basis of $V/U$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Let $U$ be a subspace of $V$. Then $V/U=\{v+U:v\in V\}$.

Addition on $V/U$ is defined by $(v+U)+(w+U)=(v+w)+U$ and scalar multiplication is defined by $\lambda (v+U)=\lambda v+U$.

If a basis of $V$ is $v_1,\dots,v_n$. Is $v_1+U,\dots,v_n+U$ a basis of $V/U$ using the operations of addition and scalar multiplication above? For every $v\in V$ we have that $v=a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n$. Then using the definition of addition and scalar multiplication defined above, for $v+U\in V/U$ we have that $v+U=a_1(v_1+U)+\dots+a_n(v_n+U)$.

The reason I ask this question is that, if this is true, then that would imply that $\dim V=\dim V/U$. But another result tells us that $\dim V/U=\dim V-\dim U$.

If the above result were to hold, that would imply that $\dim U=0$ and that $U=\{0\}$. Which doesn't have to the case always. I am pretty sure I am missing something, but I just can't figure out what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$v_1+U,\dots,v_n+U$ spans $V/U$ but it is not linearly indeprndent. For example, $v_1+U=v_2+U$ if $v_1-v_2 \in U$.

Specific example: Let $V=\mathbb  R^{2},U=\{(x,x): x \in \mathbb R\}$. Let $v_1=(1,0), v_2=(0,-1)$ Then $v_1,v_2$ is  a basis for $V$ but $v_1-v_2=(1,1) \in U$ and $v_1+U=v_2+U$.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn’t think about linear independence. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The answer is, as you hint at, no unless $U=0$.  The set $\left\{v_{1}+U,...,v_{n}+U\right\}$ is a generating set for $V/U$, but generally not linearly independent.

Consider the following example. Put \begin{equation}V=\mathbb{R}^{3},\quad U=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} x\\x\\x\end{bmatrix}\right\},\quad v_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},v_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},v_{3}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}. \end{equation}

Then $(v_{1}+U)+(v_{2}+U)+(v_{3}+U)=0$ as $v_{1}+v_{2}+v_{3}\in U$, so the set is not linearly independent.

If you are stuck on this kind of question, making up a simple example is often helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I should have thought about linear  Independence but I didn’t.